# Dropdown searchbox react

Tags: reactjs

Trying to make a dynamic search dropdown in React which pulls data from an API. The biggest problem I have is figuring out how to make an input form that will show the results and allow the user to click result. I've tried React-Select but it seems buggy and doesn't work with onChange. Does anyone know of a somewhat elegant solution?

```
fetchSearchResults = query => {
        const searchUrl = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${query}&limit=10&exchange=NASDAQ`

        if (this.cancel) {
            this.cancel.cancel()
        }

        this.cancel = axios.CancelToken.source()

        axios.get( searchUrl, {cancelToken: this.cancel.token} )
        .then(res => {
            // const resultNotFound = 
                console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if(axios.isCancel(error) || error) {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                })
            }
        })

    }
```

```
 <form>
 <input value={query} onChange={this.handleOnInputChange}></input>
 </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The spec isn't clear to me here... what fields is the form supposed to consist of and how is the user supposed to interact with it? What gets put into the dropdown and what actions are supposed to occur? What "seems buggy" specifically? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: is anything returned if you console.log(res.data)?

Comment: So does `handleOnInputChange = (e) => fetchSearchResults(e.target.value);`?  It doesn't seem like the code up top is relevant at all.  Is there something I'm missing in the question?

Comment: Sorry edited for brevity. `handleOnInputChange = event =>{
        const query = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ query: query, loading:true, message: '' }, () => {
            this.fetchSearchResults(1, query)
        })
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I did the search box, you can select the exchange that you want, plus fill the query it will search and display the data:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='app'></div>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

here is the react part:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }
}

class SearchForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = [...event.target.elements].reduce((data, element) => {         
      if (element.name && element.value) {
        data[element.name] = element.value;
     }
      return data;
    }, {});

   let url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${data.query}&&limit=10`;
    if(data.exchange !== 'ALL') {
        url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${data.query}&&limit=10&&exchange=${data.exchange}`
    }


   axios.get(url)
    .then((res) => { 
    let array = res.data;
      $('#foo').empty();

     let list = $('<ul/>');  
     for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            let item = $('<li/>');
          item.append(array[i].symbol +' | ' + array[i].name+' | '+ array[i].stockExchange );
            list.append(item);
      }
    $('#foo').append(list);

    })
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <form action="/search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <select name="exchange">
          <option value="ALL" selected>ALL</option>
          <option value="NASDAQ">NYSE</option>
          <option value="NYSE">NASDAQ</option>
          <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
          <option value="EURONEXT">EURONEXT</option>
          <option value="TSX">TSX</option>
          <option value="MUTUAL_FUND">MUTUAL_FUND</option>
          <option value="COMMODITY">COMMODITY</option>
          <option value="INDEX">INDEX</option>
          <option value="CRYPTO">CRYPTO</option>
          <option value="FOREX">FOREX</option>
          <option value="TSX">TSX</option>
          <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
          <option value="EURONEXT">EURONEXT</option>
        </select>
        <button>Find</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is the css:

```
body {
   margin: 20px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/prem7qdx/2/

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }
 }
 

class SearchForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = [...event.target.elements].reduce((data, element) => {
     if (element.name && element.value) {
        data[element.name] = element.value;
      }
  
      return data;
    }, {});
    
   let url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${data.query}&&limit=10`;
    if(data.exchange !== 'ALL') {
     url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=${data.query}&&limit=10&&exchange=${data.exchange}`
    }
    

     axios.get(url)
    .then((res) => { 
    
     let array = res.data;
      
      $('#foo').empty();

      var list = $('<ul/>');  
      for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         let item = $('<li/>');
          item.append(array[i].symbol+' | '+ array[i].name+' | '+ array[i].stockExchange );
         list.append(item);

      }
 
   $('#foo').append(list);
   
    })
  };
  

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="/search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <select name="exchange" defaultValue={'ALL'}>
          <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
          <option value="NASDAQ">NYSE</option>
          <option value="NYSE">NASDAQ</option>
          <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
          <option value="EURONEXT">EURONEXT</option>
          <option value="TSX">TSX</option>
          <option value="MUTUAL_FUND">MUTUAL_FUND</option>
          <option value="COMMODITY">COMMODITY</option>
          <option value="INDEX">INDEX</option>
          <option value="CRYPTO">CRYPTO</option>
          <option value="FOREX">FOREX</option>
          <option value="TSX">TSX</option>
          <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
          <option value="EURONEXT">EURONEXT</option>
        </select>
        <button>Find</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.4/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.12.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>


<div id='app'>
</div>
<div id="foo"></div>
```